# Translate ASP pages on the fly

Tags: plugins, asp-classic, translation

Recently i came into a software solution which is developed in ASP and it works only in Internet Explorer. The software is English language and therefore i need to translate it in another language in order to present it to the audience more efficiently.

The problem is that the software was developed with out using resources, and so all the words, sentences etc. that has to be translated are in the code and we have to go line by line to do the translation.

Do you know if there is an IE plugin which can translate the ASP files according to our input in any language?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I doubt there is such plugin or tool, your best choice is moving all the strings now to external resources - better late than never!

Comment: if such tool/plugin exists, seems like a inefficent way to do the things as hell

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Google Translater https://translate.google.com/manager/  It runs on the client side and seems to translate pages well enough.